# Deezer Player never enter in PLAYBACK_COMPLETED state

Tags: android, deezer

I created an app that use the Deezer player, when I'm play track the *Player* goes for the normal states before the *PLAYING*, but when the track finish, it never enter in PLAYBACK_COMPLETED state.
In the Player object I set a *OnPlayerStateChangeListener* for check the *Player* states.

When the track finish I see in the log to be repeating this message (with TAG *AudioTrack*):

```
obtainBuffer() track 0x17c400 disbled, restarting
```

I use the Deezer API v0.9.3 and Android 4.0 (API 14) or greater.

Thanks!

## Update

With the new version of SDK (0.10.10) the player state enter in PLAYBACK_COMPLETED and the problem is solved

Comment: Hi, I tried reproducing your issue but I do get the Playback completed event. Could you post your code to see if something is missing ? also did you try with the Deezer SDK v0.10.10 ?

Comment: Hello, this is the [code](https://gist.github.com/walterjuanp/9474937) with v0.9.3 (and v0.10.10) when track finish it never enter in PLAYBACK_COMPLETED. This time I test in Android 4.0

Comment: In your code, you you modify the content of your text view directly inside the callback (with the writeLog method), but this should be done on the UI thread. Try using the runOnUiThread inside your writeLog method to make the logs appear correctly

Comment: I update the code using Log.d [this is the demo](https://github.com/walterjuanp/android_deezer_demo) and I have the same issue, do you know what it can be?